# User count of a presence room without joining

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

So, I have a Laravel/Vue project I am working on
When someone joins the app, it shows them a list of available rooms. These are presence rooms.
What I WANT is to show how many users are currently in each room on that room list before the user joins the room.

I am using Pusher for all of this.

Any suggestions or direction people can give me to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use getChannelInfo method from the SDK: https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php#get-information-about-a-channel

Comment: This is a great read but is there an example on how I would use this within Laravel/Vue? Basically how do you accomplish this using Echo or do I have to directly touch the HTTP API

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Echo, you will likely need to use the http api (which that method is basically a wrapper for, plus it handles authentication).